# How do I make structured array loop output what I want

Tags: c

I'm trying to input a number in each structure but I keep getting numbers I didn't even input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct reg {
  int course_num;
};

int main() {
  struct reg arr_reg[2];
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("Enter course number: ");
    scanf("%d"), &arr_reg[i].course_num;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("course number: %d\n ", arr_reg[i].course_num);
  }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d"), &arr_reg[i].course_num;` -> `scanf("%d", &arr_reg[i].course_num);`

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix, move the `, &arr_reg[i].course_num` into the parenthesis after the closing quotation mark. Check your IDE's error flags whenever they pop up.

Comment: Got ninjad, check Kiran's comment

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake ,change "scanf("%d"), &arr_reg[i].course_num;"
to "scanf("%d",&arr_reg[i].course_num);"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct reg{
int course_num;
};

int main()
{
    struct reg arr_reg[2];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter course number: ");
        scanf("%d",&arr_reg[i].course_num);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("course number: %d\n ", arr_reg[i].course_num);
    }
return 0;
}
```